# JavaScript event stopPropagation not working

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown with two inputs.. on the first two when I press + or - .. it increments or decrements the value.. but it closes my dropdown and starts my form..

```js
// Prevent closing dropdown on click minus button
document.querySelector("button.bk-search-minus").addEventListener("click", preventDropdownClose);
// Prevent closing dropdown on click plus button
document.querySelector("button.bk-search-plus").addEventListener("click", preventDropdownClose);


// Prevent closing dropdown
function preventDropdownClose(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}

function incrementValueInput(parentNode, event) {
    var quantityEl = parentNode.querySelector('.quantity');
    var value = parseInt(quantityEl.getAttribute('data-value'));
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    quantityEl.setAttribute('data-value', value);
    quantityEl.textContent = value;

    // Add event listener to select to prevent closing dropdown
    select.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation()
    });
}

function decrementValueInput(parentNode, event) {
    var quantityEl = parentNode.querySelector('.quantity');
    var value = parseInt(quantityEl.getAttribute('data-value'));
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value--;
    value = value < 0 ? 0 : value;
    quantityEl.setAttribute('data-value', value);
    quantityEl.textContent = value;
}
```

```html
                <form id="booking-search-form" action="https://www.booking.com/searchresults.ro.html" method="get"
                    target="_blank" style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="hakolal-search-row-bk">
                            <div class="col-sm hakolal-search-conf">
                                <label class="hakolal-datepiker">צ’ק אין</label>
                                <input class="hk-datepicker-input" type="date" id="checkin" name="checkin">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm hakolal-search-conf">
                                <label class="hakolal-datepiker">צ’ק אווט</label>
                                <input class="hk-datepicker-input" type="date" id="checkout" name="checkout">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm hakolal-search-conf">
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle hk-numb-of-guest" type="button"
                                        id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                                        aria-expanded="true">
                                        <img class="bk-search-icon dropdown-hk"
                                            src="/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/groups_FILL0_wght400_GRAD0_opsz48.svg"
                                            alt="children"><span>מספר אורחים</span></button>
                                    <div id="content" class="content dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                                        <div class="modal-header hk-bk-search">
                                            <button type="button" class="close-hk-search" data-dismiss="modal"
                                                aria-label="Close">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="list number-input">
                                            <img class="bk-search-icon"
                                                src="/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/8725461_bed_double_icon.svg"
                                                alt="room">
                                            <label for="rooms" class="list">חדר</label>
                                            <div style="position: absolute; left: 5%; display: flex;"
                                                class="search-button-section">
                                                <button onclick="decrementValueInput(this.parentNode)"
                                                    class="bk-search-minus">
                                                    -
                                                </button>

                                                <div id="bk-room" class="quantity bk-search-input" data-value="1"
                                                    contenteditable="false" onclick="preventDropdownClose(event)">1
                                                </div>

                                                <button onclick="incrementValueInput(this.parentNode)"
                                                    class="bk-search-plus">
                                                    +
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="list number-input" id="adults-list">
                                            <img class="bk-search-icon"
                                                src="/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/person_FILL0_wght400_GRAD0_opsz48.svg"
                                                alt="adults">
                                            <label for="adults" class="list">שני מבוגרים</label>
                                            <div style="position: absolute; left: 5%; display: flex;"
                                                class="search-button-section">
                                                <button onclick="decrementValueInput(this.parentNode)"
                                                    class="bk-search-minus">
                                                    -
                                                </button>

                                                <div id="bk-adults" class="quantity bk-search-input" data-value="2"
                                                    contenteditable="false" onclick="preventDropdownClose(event)">2
                                                </div>

                                                <button onclick="incrementValueInput(this.parentNode)"
                                                    class="bk-search-plus">
                                                    +
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="list number-input" id="children-list">
                                            <img class="bk-search-icon"
                                                src="/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/child_care_FILL0_wght400_GRAD0_opsz48.svg"
                                                alt="children">
                                            <label for="children" class="list">0 ילד</label>
                                            <div style="position: absolute; left: 5%; display: flex;"
                                                search-button-section">
                                                <div class="bk-search-minus" onclick="decrementValue(this.parentNode, event)">
                                                    -
                                                </div>

                                                <div id="bk-childrens" class="quantity bk-search-input" data-value="0"
                                                    contenteditable="false" onclick="preventDropdownClose(event)">
                                                    0
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="bk-search-plus" onclick="incrementValue(this.parentNode, event)">
                                                    +
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="children-ages"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm hakolal-search-conf">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info hakolal-search-bk">לחפש</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

it would help me a lot if you could help me .. I can't figure it out .. why does the dropdown close every time I press + or - ..

Here is part of JS for children..

```
// function for plus button to increase value
function incrementValue(parentNode) {
    var quantityEl = parentNode.querySelector('.quantity');
    var value = parseInt(quantityEl.getAttribute('data-value'));
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    quantityEl.setAttribute('data-value', value);
    quantityEl.textContent = value;

    const childrenAgesDiv = document.querySelector("#children-ages");
    const select = document.createElement("select");
    select.setAttribute("id", `child-${value}-age`);
    select.setAttribute("name", `age-${value}`);
    select.classList.add("bk-search-age");

    for (let j = 1; j <= 17; j++) {
        const option = document.createElement("option");
        option.setAttribute("value", j);
        option.innerText = j;
        select.appendChild(option);
    }

    const label = document.createElement("label");
    label.setAttribute("for", `child-${value}-age`);
    label.classList.add("bk-search-age");
    label.innerText = `גיל ילד ${value}`;

    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add("bk-search-select-row");
    div.appendChild(label);
    div.appendChild(select);
    childrenAgesDiv.appendChild(div);

    // Add event listener to select to prevent closing dropdown
    select.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

    // Prevent closing dropdown
    event.stopPropagation();
}

// function for minus button to decrease value
function decrementValue(parentNode) {
    var quantityEl = parentNode.querySelector('.quantity');
    var value = parseInt(quantityEl.getAttribute('data-value'));
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value--;
    value = value < 0 ? 0 : value;
    quantityEl.setAttribute('data-value', value);
    quantityEl.textContent = value;

    const childrenAgesDiv = document.querySelector("#children-ages");
    if (childrenAgesDiv.children.length > 0) {
        childrenAgesDiv.removeChild(childrenAgesDiv.lastChild);
    }

    // Prevent closing dropdown
    event.stopPropagation();
}

// Prevent closing dropdown
function preventDropdownClose(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

but here it works perfectly.. it doesn't close my dropdown when clicking + or -. Any help here ?

Answer (score 0):

While HTML event attributes such as `onclick`, do trigger the supplied callback, that callback is not automatically passed a reference to the `event` object that triggered the event in the first place. Additionally, your event callbacks have a second argument of `event`, but you don't call the callback with a second argument, so `event` is `undefined`.

Here's an example:

```js
function foo(e){
  console.log(e);  // No event argument is passed
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="foo()">Click Me</button>
```

When you set up events with `.addEventListener()`, the callback is automatically passed (as the first argument) a reference to the `event` object, so using that technique (which is the correct modern way) works.

And an example:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", foo);


function foo(e){
  console.log(e);  // Event argument is passed
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: I changed the approach based on what you wrote to me.. but I think I'm wrong somewhere.. that I can't figure it out yet :))
I attach the code
// Prevent closing dropdown
function preventDropdownClose(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}

// Prevent closing dropdown on click minus button
document.querySelector("button.bk-search-minus").addEventListener("click", preventDropdownClose);
// Prevent closing dropdown on click plus button
document.querySelector("button.bk-search-plus").addEventListener("click", preventDropdownClose);

Comment: @EMC-DEV If you use `.addEventListener()`, remember the the event reference will automatically become the first argument passed to your callback.

Comment: @EMC-DEV Please edit your question with the new code, don't add it as a comment.

Comment: @EMC-DEV Also, remember that pressing + and - are not `click` events, they are `keydown` and `keyup` events, so stopping a `click` event won't affect that.

Comment: ok, i update the code. What do you recommend? to use for keydown and keyup